# Positioning table elements differently on mobile

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a table that on desktop has an image on the left and text on the right. On mobile the text needs to act as a header so should sit on top. I've tried floating this to the right but that hasn't worked.

I need the table to be 100% of the width of the screen with all of its elements centered. Here's the code I'm currently using which works fine but places the image on the top.

```css
.site-section-content {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .site-section-wrap {
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      background: pink;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-flow: row;
      text-align: center;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .site-section-wrap {
      width: 100%;
      display: table;
      background: pink;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
    }
    }

    .site-section-title-section {
      width: 50%;
      float: right;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .site-section-title-section {
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
    }
    }

    .site-section-info-section {
      width: 50%;
      float: right;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .site-section-info-section {
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
    }
    }
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <div class="site-section-content">
       <div class="site-section-wrap">
          <div class="site-section-title-section">
                 <p>Left on Desktop | Bottom on Mobile (when stacked)</p>
          </div>
          <div class="site-section-info-section">
                <p><p>Right on Desktop | Top on Mobile (when stacked)</p></p>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

I may alternate the images so that some are on the left and some on the right so I'd change the tags around for that, like this.

```css
.site-section-content {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .site-section-wrap {
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      background: pink;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-flow: row;
      text-align: center;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .site-section-wrap {
      width: 100%;
      display: table;
      background: pink;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
    }
    }

    .site-section-title-section {
      width: 50%;
      float: right;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .site-section-title-section {
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
    }
    }

    .site-section-info-section {
      width: 50%;
      float: right;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .site-section-info-section {
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
    }
    }
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<div class="site-section-content">
   <div class="site-section-wrap">
      <div class="site-section-title-section">
         <p>Left on Desktop | Bottom on Mobile (when stacked)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="site-section-info-section">
         <p>
         <p>Right on Desktop | Top on Mobile (when stacked)</p>
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="site-section-wrap">
      <div class="site-section-info-section">
         <p>
         <p>Left on Desktop | Bottom on Mobile (when stacked)</p>
         </p>
      </div>
      <div class="site-section-title-section">
         <p>Right on Desktop | Top on Mobile (when stacked)</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

So ideally the desktop site would look like this:
[image: Desktop Site]

The mobile version like this:
[image: Mobile Version]

And have this potential ideally (although all images could be on the left, it wouldn't look as good)
[image: Desktop Alternative]

I could just name the outer wrappers left and right then place content accordingly but the text would always need to be on top. I've attempted to use a mix of flex (to center things) and table (for mobile) but I'm open to alternative approaches if they'd make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

no need of using floats, just do it with `flex-direction`

```css
.site-section-content {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .site-section-wrap {
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      background: pink;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {      
      .site-section-wrap {flex-direction: column-reverse;}
    }
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<div class="site-section-content">
   <div class="site-section-wrap">
      <div class="site-section-title-section">
         <p>Left on Desktop | Bottom on Mobile (when stacked)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="site-section-info-section">
         <p>Right on Desktop | Top on Mobile (when stacked)</p>
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="site-section-wrap">
      <div class="site-section-info-section">
         <p>
         <p>Left on Desktop | Bottom on Mobile (when stacked)</p>
         </p>
      </div>
      <div class="site-section-title-section">
         <p>Right on Desktop | Top on Mobile (when stacked)</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```